# Why am I able to use web service as a java application but not possible with struts2

Tags: java, web-services, struts2, sslhandshakeexception

I am creating a web service Client.Following are the points to be noted:

- I should not add the certificate to the cacerts or jssecacert (any keystore).
- So I am using a naive trustmanager (trusts all certificates)
- I am able to use the webservice and get the result when I do it as a regular java application.
- If I copy the same code into my struts2, it does not work.

The code is:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class main {

/**
 * @param args
 */

static {
    System.out.println("Inside static block");
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hostname.equals("***.***.**.**")) {
                System.out.println("verify success");
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("Verify unsuccessful");
            return false;
        }
    });
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } };
    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    }
    // Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the
    // truststore
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://path.service.asmx?WSDL");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    }

    Service o_service = new Service();
    ServiceSoap o_serServiceSoap = o_service.getServiceSoap();
    System.out.println(o_serServiceSoap.getUserInformation("information",
            "information", "information", "information", "information"));

}

}
```

The same code when copied into my struts2 project gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://path.service.asmx: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1282)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1238)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1295)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: In this bit `catch (GeneralSecurityException e) { }` you might be swallowing the cause of the problem. replace it with `catch (GeneralSecurityException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: you are putting this into action class? main method?

Comment: That error is sometimes raised when it cannot access truststore and/or keystore (check javax.net.ssl.keystore and javax.net.ssl.truststore system properties to see who are you referring to)

Comment: @NGoyal: Yes I am putting it into the action class.

Comment: can you post that code in here... action class... may be that could give a clear picture..

Comment: It is the same thing. Except that I am writing it in an execute() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] 79 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: ***PKIX path building failed***: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: ***unable to find valid certification path to requested target*** at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) at [...]

That is the important part of your stacktrace.

[This article](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) esplains what's happening and how to fix it.

You can try following the [Mkyong article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) (based on the one above), that could be a little easier.

Also ensure you have configured your Application Server to support SSL and HTTPS ([Tomcat Example](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)).

Comment: I went through that article. But my first and most important criteria is that I don't want to install the certificate. Is there any other way ?